# What about unknown or hidden folders in android after connecting with PC?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, file-system

My iBall BraceX1 tablet runs on Android 4.4.2.

Whenever I connect my tablet with my PC, I see folders that I marked in following snap.

[image]

Please let me know about these folders.

Regards
FewL

Answer (score 0):

These appear to be hidden folders in your external storage.

> Android is based on Linux, and that fact shows itself in how it
>   handles files and folders. To keep it short, Linux/Unix, and therefore
>   Android, hides any file that starts with a dot `.`, which has become
>   a common convention to hide certain things that users wouldn’t
>   normally need to care about, like app config/settings, databases etc.

You wouldn't normally view these files on your Android device, sd card even though these directories are present. As such you could use suitable file explorers such ES explorer, Astro manager etc to unhide these directories.

Unlike Unix/Linux systems, Windows doesn't hide files/folders that start with a `.` (dot prefix), and thus are visible when the sd card is mounted on a Windows system.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue ?